# What are some good survey articles for automorphic forms?

Tags: reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference for automorphic forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46670/reference-for-automorphic-forms)

Does anyone know of any good survey articles that deal with the theory of autmorphic forms? I have read the chapter on modular forms in Serre's book. As for my background knowledge, I'm fine with anything undergraduate/beginning graduate level.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent book at that level is "The 1-2-3 of Modular Forms" by Bruinier, van der Geer, Harder, and Zagier.  The title is a little cheesy, but it refers to the fact that the book contains three long surveys : one on classical modular forms, one on Hilbert modular forms, and one on Siegel modular forms.

Comment: Adding link to the recommended [book](http://www.amazon.com/1-2-3-Modular-Forms-Nordfjordeid-Universitext/dp/3540741178) on the Amazon.